# Копирование файлов из папки по списку IP

Tags: c#, .net, share

подскажите пожалуйста, есть список айпи (ip.txt), есть папка File, мне нужно чтобы все файлы содержащиеся в папке File были скопированы по списку Ip из файла ip.txt, к каждому ip свой логин и пароль, получается чтобы нужно методом перебора логинов и паролей подключаться по Ip. и копировал на диск D в папку Dir , если вбить в ручную айпи,то работает,но мне нужно брать айпи и логины с ip.txt , login.txt , pass.txt , как можно это реализовать?

```
                string username = "username";//список логинов
                string password = "Password";//список паролей
                string FirstDir = @"\\...\File"
                string SecondDir = @"\\ip\d$\Dir"
                DisconnectFromShare(SecondDir, true); 
                ConnectToShare(SecondDir, username, password); 
                File.Copy(FirstDir, SecondDir);
                DisconnectFromShare(SecondDir, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, зачем данные об одном хочте хранить в разных файлах?

Ну да ладно, допустим, что количество элементов в массивах одинаковое, и каждый элемент сопоставляется по индексу между файлами (вы забыли объяснить, что там у вас на самом деле):

```
string[] ip = File.ReadAllLines("ip.txt");
string[] login = File.ReadAllLines("login.txt");
string[] pass = File.ReadAllLines("pass.txt");
string firstDir = @"\\...\File";

for (int i = 0; i < ip.Length; i++)
{
    string secondDir = $@"\\{ip[i]}\d$\Dir";
    ConnectToShare(secondDir, login[i], pass[i]); 
    foreach (string sourcePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(firstDir))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(secondDir, fileName);
        File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
    DisconnectFromShare(secondDir, false);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: скажите пожалуйста,как можно реализовать перебор логинов и паролей для каждого Ip?

Comment: @Alex это уже похоже на вредоносную деятельность, ее мы здесь не обсуждаем. И я думаю, что винда не позволит вам выполнить брутфорс-атаку на сеть, просто заблокирует возможность подключения и все, либо будет отвечать с очень большими задержками. Так что в этом практически нет никакого смысла.